# Maximum finder not working

Tags: swift, function, closures, short

I have got this code:

```
func doSomething(_ closure: ([Double]?, Double?) -> Double?) {
    closure([1,2,3,4], 8)
}
print(doSomething({ return $0?.max() ?? $1}))
```

I need help understanding why it does not return anything, when it should return the maximum in array, or the second parameter.

Comment: Your function does not return anything – have a look at the compiler warnings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doSomething` is a *void* function. Taking a parameter of type `(([Double]?, Double?) -> Double?)` does not mean that the function itself should returns `Double?`

Although the function seems *weird* to me, I assume that what are you trying to achieve is:

```
func doSomething(_ closure: ([Double]?, Double?) -> Double?) -> Double? {
    return closure([1,2,3,4], 8)
}
```

After this edit, the output should be:

```
print(doSomething { return $0?.max() ?? $1 }) // Optional(4.0)
```

For such a case, I'd suggest to unwrap it safely, you might want to "Optional Binding" it:

```
if let value = doSomething({ return $0?.max() ?? $1}) {
    print(value) // 4.0
}
```